# Managing spacing around \section inside a minipage with titlesec

Tags: sectioning, minipage, titlesec

I'm having some trouble getting proper padding around my section headers inside minipages.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}

\newcommand\Vhrulefill{\leaders\hrule height 0.7ex depth \dimexpr0.4pt-0.7ex\hfill\kern0pt}
\titleformat{\section}{\bfseries\large}{}{0pt}{\noindent\Vhrulefill~#1~\Vhrulefill}

\begin{document}
    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.45\textwidth}
        \section{Introduction}
            Some content for the first section
        \section{One More Section}
            \begin{itemize}
                \item Item 1
                \item Item 2
            \end{itemize}
        \section{Another Section}
            Some text outside of a list here
        \section{Last section}
            \begin{itemize}
                \item One here
                \item One more
            \end{itemize}
    \end{minipage}%
    \hfill\vline\hfill
    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.45\textwidth}
        \section{Introduction}
            Some content for the first section
        \section{One More Section}
            \begin{itemize}
                \item Item 1
                \item Item 2
            \end{itemize}
        \section{Another Section}
            Some text outside of a list here
        \section{Last section}
            \begin{itemize}
                \item One here
                \item One more
            \end{itemize}
    \end{minipage}%
\end{document}
```

[image: demo]

There's too little spacing before "One More Section" and too much after.

When I try to adjust it with `\titlespacing`, it doesn't affect all the sections

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here are 3 solutions

1. Using `multicols` environment from `multicol` package
   [image]

---

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\usepackage{multicol}

\newcommand\Vhrulefill{\leaders\hrule height 0.7ex depth \dimexpr0.4pt-0.7ex\hfill\kern0pt}
\titleformat{\section}{\bfseries\large}{}{0pt}{\noindent\Vhrulefill~#1~\Vhrulefill}

\setlength\columnseprule{.4pt}
%\setlength\columnsep{12pt}
\begin{document}
\begin{multicols}{2}
\section{Introduction}
 Some content for the first section
\section{One More Section}
\begin{itemize}
   \item Item 1
   \item Item 2
\end{itemize}
\section{Another Section}
Some text outside of a list here
\section{Last section}
\begin{itemize}
    \item One here
    \item One more
\end{itemize}

%\columnbreak

\section{Introduction}
 Some content for the first section
\section{One More Section}
\begin{itemize}
   \item Item 1
   \item Item 2
\end{itemize}
\section{Another Section}
Some text outside of a list here
\section{Last section}
\begin{itemize}
    \item One here
    \item One more
\end{itemize}
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

2. Using `parbox` command
   [image]

---

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}

\newcommand\Vhrulefill{\leaders\hrule height 0.7ex depth \dimexpr0.4pt-0.7ex\hfill\kern0pt}
\titleformat{\section}{\bfseries\large}{}{0pt}{\noindent\Vhrulefill~#1~\Vhrulefill}

\begin{document}
\parbox[t]{0.45\textwidth}{%
\section{Introduction}
 Some content for the first section
\section{One More Section}
\begin{itemize}
   \item Item 1
   \item Item 2
\end{itemize}
\section{Another Section}
Some text outside of a list here
\section{Last section}
\begin{itemize}
    \item One here
    \item One more
\end{itemize}
}%
\hfill\vline\hfill
\parbox[t]{0.45\textwidth}{%
\section{Introduction}
 Some content for the first section
\section{One More Section}
\begin{itemize}
   \item Item 1
   \item Item 2
\end{itemize}
\section{Another Section}
Some text outside of a list here
\section{Last section}
\begin{itemize}
    \item One here
    \item One more
\end{itemize}
}
\end{document}
```

3. A work around `minipage` it seems that we can't start a minipage with `\section` so we used `\` (space) or `~`
   [image]

---

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}

\newcommand*\thirdoffive[5]{#3}
\makeatletter
\newcommand*\mt{\vskip-\expandafter\thirdoffive\ttls@section\ }
\makeatother
\newcommand\Vhrulefill{\leaders\hrule height 0.7ex depth \dimexpr0.4pt-0.7ex\hfill\kern0pt}
\titleformat{\section}{\bfseries\large}{}{0pt}{\noindent\Vhrulefill~#1~\Vhrulefill}

\begin{document}
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.45\textwidth}\mt
\section{Introduction}
 Some content for the first section
\section{One More Section}
\begin{itemize}
   \item Item 1
   \item Item 2
\end{itemize}
\section{Another Section}
Some text outside of a list here
\section{Last section}
\begin{itemize}
    \item One here
    \item One more
\end{itemize}
\end{minipage}%
\hfill\vline\hfill
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.45\textwidth}\mt
\section{Introduction}
 Some content for the first section
\section{One More Section}
\begin{itemize}
   \item Item 1
   \item Item 2
\end{itemize}
\section{Another Section}
Some text outside of a list here
\section{Last section}
\begin{itemize}
    \item One here
    \item One more
\end{itemize}
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You're amazing! I used your third solution.