# Spacing around \section and \subsection with titlesec and minipage

Tags: minipage, titlesec, subsection

In the following MWE, it seems like minipage and titlesec interact with each other. If I use either one OR the other, the spacing is fine, but when I use BOTH, the spacing around the section and/or subsection is wrong.

I found a workaround in another post ([Managing spacing around \section inside a minipage with titlesec](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/297498/managing-spacing-around-section-inside-a-minipage-with-titlesec)), but I still don't understand. Can someone explain what is going on?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{titlesec}

\begin{document}

     \begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
%       \mbox{}

        \section*{Section}
        \subsection*{First sub}
        \lipsum[1][1-2]
        
        \subsection*{Second sub}
        \lipsum[1][3-4]

        \subsection*{Third sub}
        \lipsum[1][5-6]
        
      \end{minipage}

\end{document
```

[image: Compiled document with/without spacing]

Comment: What happens if you delete the initial `\mbox{}`?

Comment: using sections in a minipage is a bit odd, what's the use case here? also `\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}` will be overfull as it is full width but indented by paragraph indent, you probably want `\noindent\begin{minipage}`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: The above is a simplified MWE showing the weird behavior. The document is a resume, inspired by limecv and fortysecondcv.cls, using TikZ to place the various elements, which is why I need a minipage (inside a node). I used \linewidth in the MWE, but in reality it is narrower.

Comment: @Bernard: the \mbox{} somehow corrects the spacing, like if I had either minipage OR titlesec, but not both. That's the workaround, but it looks like... magic? to me. I would like to understand what's going on.

Comment: well it's hard to say how to get correct spacing when the whole minipage is forcing the headings to be hsifted right,but anyway the box is easily explained as minipage tries to act like a page and discards space before a section  at the top you can probly disable that with `\@minipagefalse` at the start of the minipage/

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: But without the \mbox{}, the spacing also disappears between the subsections!